# Where is the wallpaper image saved?

Tags: files, images, wallpaper

I had an image from a website which I set as my wallpaper inside the browser. I am wondering now where I can find the image in the file system, because I can't find it online anymore. I am rooted.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's there, but did you check `/sdcard/downloads/`?

Comment: No. It's not in there.

Comment: There may be a change on Jellybean: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27692/where-is-current-wallpaper-stored-on-jellybean

Comment: I found mine by searching for "wallpaper" in the stock browser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the same on older systems, but on ICS it appears to save directly to `/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper`. I set mine from the browser, pulled that file, then changed it to a .png extension and *voilà* - it was the image I had set.

It also appears that this file simply gets overwritten when you change your wallpaper, so I don't see a way to recover one once it's changed unless you have a copy of the image somewhere else.

This also appears to be where it's saved on CyanogenMod 7, so it's possible that this is the "standard" location (certainly a good place to check, at least).

Comment: And now, good luck finding the same on an iPhone ! My father has the same problem, he wants to get back and transfer his wallpaper image somewhere else, and it’s nowhere to be seen in his picture library… unfortunately for him he has an iPhone, and after spending some time I’ve come to the conclusion that he’s toast. Thanks Steve, thanks Tim.

Answer (score 28):

I was annoyed by the exact same problem, so I have programmed an app that automatically saves your wallpapers and your live wallpapers too. It makes it easy to revert to a previous wallpaper. It is called [Wallpaper Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaverFree), by Appdictive, and it's free in the Play Store. (It does not require root access.)

Comment: Works, but does not find wallpapers muzei app sets each day. It finds only the default muzei background

Answer (score 9):

In Android 7.0, it's located in `/data/system/users/0`. You'll have to use a file explorer to rename it to a jpg or whatever it is. The folder also contains your lockscreen wallpaper so that's a plus.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight twist on the original question's context but may be useful to some who land here...

The location of the **stock wallpapers** is in an apk file that you should find on your device at `/system/framework/framework-res.apk`. Pull that file to your computer and then browse its internals. A search for a file with `wallpaper` in its name should prove fruitful.

The apk also contains other goodies such as stock icons.

Comment: I have checked in my Android 9 and that file has many instances of the string`wallpaper` in it which seems irrelevant. Would you mind being more specific as to how that string should look like / where / so on

Comment: In my case, I have found the `default_wallpaper.png` file in the `res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4` folder (inside `framework-res.apk`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Root Browser, ES File Explorer, or other root folder browsers for this. Go to the root path using Root Browser (or ES File Explorer), and then:

```
data/data/com.cmcm.locker/cache/Volley/dat
```

When you try to open it, it won't open. To open it:

1. Copy the images with high size (maybe more than 80 KB since they got a quality) and paste them into a folder that is not in a root directory. (Just copy it to your "Downloads" folder or to your SD card)
2. Rename it. But when you do this, don't forget the ".jpg" at the end of the name you type. E.g. If I rename it to, "Sukkoth.jpg"
3. Open it using Gallery or any image viewer app.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 7.1.2, I found them here, but they do not have an extension:

```
/data/data/com.android.wallpaperbackup/files   
    wallpaper-lock-stage  
    wallpaper-stage
```

and here too as suggested on [SiriusXM's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/167978/44325):

```
/data/system/users/0    
   wallpaper    
   wallpaper_lock   
   wallpaper_lock_orig    
   wallpaper_orig
```

Image extension can simply be added to those files.

Answer (score 1):

in Android 9 (my S10+), wallpapers (lock & regular) are stored in:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.systemui/files/backupwallpapers/
```

Comment: This is correct for me. Also using an S10.

Answer (score 0):

I found my wallpaper in the location `\Internal Storage\WhatsApp\Media\WallPaper` after a search for "wallpaper" in Windows Explorer after connecting the phone to the computer.

Answer (score -2):

Try here: `Internal Storage/Android/data/com.android.systemui` under internal storage.