# Where is current wallpaper stored on Jellybean?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.1-jelly-bean, wallpaper

On my Nexus S running 4.1.1, I am unable to find where the current wallpaper is stored. I referred to [Where is the background image saved?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18450/where-is-the-background-image-saved), but my `/data/data/com.android.settings/files` folder is empty (I do have my file browser showing hidden files). It was confirmed in that question that ICS stored it in that location, but did Jellybean move it to a different place?

Comment: Unless you are rooted (Thanks @Izzy) you can't see the files and folders under /data folder. I am running 4.1.1 CM10 and as I am rooted, I can see files and folders under /data

Comment: In my CM10 4.1.1, I do not have "/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper" but under "/data/data/com.android.settings/" I have folders: cache, lib, shared_prefs only. And only share_prefs folder is not empty with two xml files with no pointer to wallpaper info.

Comment: I switched file browsers and now have a similar situation to @Narayanan where the shared_prefs is the only folder with files in it. The files folder isempty

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The wallpaper was in

```
data/data/com.android.settings/files/
```

on previous versions of Android. However it appears that it was moved as part of the multi-user preparations. The current location is

```
data/system/users/0/
```

The file is conveniently called wallpaper and it is a png file.

Comment: I am not using  default wallpaper, and my files folder is empty (see my comment on the question). Is there some utility that let's you see what files are being modified?

Comment: @penguinrob It's not moved in JB. What do you mean by being modified?

Comment: On Mac, I can use fs_usage to monitor what files an application accesses. I'm wondering if there's something similar that could be used to see what files are modified when I change the wallpaper.

Comment: @penguinrob you're right it was moved. I haven't noticed as I haven't wiped when I upgraded to JB.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one then!

Comment: I looked in /data/system/users/0 and I found the wallpaper file but none of apps will read it when opened as an image even after renaming it.

Comment: @damastah you need to copy it to your SD card. Normal apps can't open images from /data

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to retrieve the wallpaper as well but found it too difficult. 
So to solve this I have create the app "Wallpaper Saver". It automatically saves your wallpapers and makes it easy to restore an old wallpaper again. It also supports live wallpapers. It is free to use.
You can download it from Play:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaverFree